# How to search for libraries in multiplatform cmake builds?

Tags: dll, cmake, shared-libraries, cross-platform

I am searching for a nice way to handle linked libs in cmake. In my case the cmake configuration file(CMakeLists.txt) is executed in Linux environments and on cygwin on Windows.
The build process contains two libs. libA is build from sources and only depends on the std. C API. libB is build, as well, from sources and includes the libA. The libs are build separately(with an own git repro).

By defining in cmake at "libB/CMakeLists.txt"

```
find_library (libB A)
```

I am linking libB against libA. When linking under cygwin, this line fails. When I change it to

```
find_library (libB ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH}/static/libA.dll.a)
```

it works.

Both libs are build as shared libs.

"libA/CMakeLists.txt":

```
add_library(libA SHARED ${libA_source})
install(
        TARGETS libA 
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}/static
    )
```

and

"libB/CMakeLists.txt":

```
add_library(libB SHARED ${libB_source})
install(
        TARGETS libB 
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}/static
    )
```

Under Linux this works fine. The libs are placed into "/user/local/lib". Under Windows the libs are placed into "/user/local/lib/shared" + the dlls are placed into "/user/local/bin".

The statement to link libB against libA changes to ("libB/CMakeLists.txt"):

```
if (UNIX)
  find_library (libB A)
elseif (CYGWIN)
  find_library (libB ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH}/static/libA.dll.a)
endif()
```

Any idea how to handle the linker references of these two builds in a simple - maybe - platform independent line?

Comment: Instead of `find_library` call it should be `target_link_libraries`, isn't it?

Comment: Lib A and B are dependent, but build separately. No chance to use target_link_libraries to link the projects.

Comment: You must have misunderstood the purpose the commands. Target_link_libraries is used to compile libraries the project creates itself. Find_library is to find external libraries. You are mixing them up.

Comment: This is true. With `find_library (libB A)` you are creating a variable `libB` which contains the location of library A.

Comment: I am searching a way to avoid checking the build toolchains and selecting the link libs after. modified the question to point this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work within your libB/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_library(libA 
             NAMES A libA libA.so libA.dll libA.dll.a
             HINTS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}
)
target_link_libraries(libB ${libA})
```

Check the path to libA with

```
message(STATUS "libA=${libA}")
```